# How does Canonical sustain its finances?

Tags: canonical

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Ubuntu make money?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21730/how-does-ubuntu-make-money)

Since Ubuntu is, and will always be, free and no many I know go for anything that is paid for ( like paid games or ubuntu one's paid features ), I wonder how come they are able to sustain finances ?