# Are the source code of commercial version of open source software encrypted or hidden from being manipuated

Tags: software-sources, open-source, commercial

Commercial version of open source softwares are the main source of revenue for canonical, red head team, oracle [for MYSQL], etc. So my question is do all these source codes hidden or encrypted from being manipulated, otherwise their will be no way of generating revenue for all these open source teams.

Comment: It can't be open-source, and also be hidden or encrypted. The terms are mutually exclusive. It's either open or it isn't. Support becomes the product, not the software.

Comment: @TomBrossman So it means that For example: MYSQL Community server is an open source but the enterprise edition isn't.

Comment: @EliahKagan Tachyons beat me to it! I thought this would be closed sooner, so didn’t bother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open source apps should share source code even if it is commercial,So if source code is hidden, it is not opensource, For eg redhat source code is available for download, But still redhat earns money from that product

Comment: Ok but how did Red-Hat manages to earn revenue from that if all these codes are available freely?

Comment: @joystick: It is offtopic here, You can do a simple google search for it, :)

Comment: All right I've figured it out. http://www.quora.com/Red-Hat-company/How-does-Red-Hat-make-money
Thanks for your help.

Comment: @joystick I think you are asking two questions here 1)[What is the definition of open source?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source) 2)[How does Ubuntu make money?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21730/12864) Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Usability is the lynchpin that makes OSS based companies stay alive.  Open source or not, most commercial companies that are founded on open source are based on UI improvements or management interfaces(the good ones anyway).

Landscape is a Canonical effort for large node number management with a simple interface.  Juju is the effort to have scripts to make deployment of specific node-types easier.

Do I think Landscape will leverage a lot of Juju scripts?  Yes, but provisioning isn't all it does.

MySQL is a separate product from the Oracle database.  They acquired it AFTER they had a functional high-end product.  Let's leave that one out.  Examine Virtualbox instead.  Virtualbox OSE has a lot of features, enough to make it usable.  If you want USB passthrough, you need the non-open-source parts.  It's still free, but would you pay $5 for USB passthrough and use Vbox or tell everyone you support to buy a $300 VMWare product?

Asterisk was used by Trixbox.  Deployment and interface.

The OSS guys get it working.  The commercial guys put on a slick UI and make it easy to deploy.  That's just how I see it.