# How does Ubuntu earn money?

Tags: software-center, canonical

From the moment that I used your OS I have become a fan. Fan of it's simplicity and beauty, but I worry about the creators. Creating something that is so simple and easy to use plus a beautiful OS requires a lot of money. Your OS is just like the Mac it is so simple to use, but unlike them you gave it for free.

I would suggest that you sort of copy apple. Make your own app store that way you'll earn money plus developers would be easily be able to make money too. Second you can sell music videos books and magazines so that it could generate income just like Android. As a Windows 8 user I find it easy to navigate to your OS. Make the apps upgradable. And I like how your OS design language fits perfectly on smartphones, tablets and TVs. I can't donate because I don't know how to use Paypal, but I think that this might help you.

Try copying what Apple and Android has done, and combine it in a way that it will attract developers and users but at the same time you could earn money. Thanks and one more thing please while developers are busy creating they're apps please create exclusive apps of your own.

Comment: Canonical (the Ubuntu developers) makes money from advertising on their website and from donations.

Answer (score 5):

In short, [Canonical](http://canonical.com) (the company behind [Ubuntu](http://ubuntu.com)) earns money from it's free and open source operating system from:

- Paid Professional Support (like the one [Redhat Inc.](http://redhat.com) offers to corporate customers)
- The [Landscape](https://landscape.canonical.com)  software
- Donations
- <s>Income from the [Ubuntu shop](http://shop.ubuntu.com), like T-shirts, accessories as well as CD packs</s> - discontinued
- Business Servers
- <s>The [Ubuntu One](http://one.ubuntu.com) Service</s> -
  discontinued
- Ubuntu's Software Center section for paid software (Canonical earns a part of that money)

You can also take a look at [How does Ubuntu make money?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21730/how-does-ubuntu-make-money)