# Who owns Ubuntu and the ownership of Ubuntu as a going concern

Tags: 11.04, canonical

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Who pays for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4489/who-pays-for-ubuntu)
>   [Ubuntu finances and future of project?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3837/ubuntu-finances-and-future-of-project)
>   [How does Ubuntu make money?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21730/how-does-ubuntu-make-money)

As I read Mark Shuttlesworth (hope i got it correct) is the one calling the shots through his owned created trust (God bless him). My question is that what will happen if he (God forbid) suddenly withdraws his funds from the Ubuntu project?

Comment: bernard we close questions like this particular one because it's answered in its entirety by other threads already. We're not keen on speculative or hypothetical discussions (because there are rarely clear answers) but in this case there have already been good answers on other threads. @phil - I think you'll agree that this isn't really censorship at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ubuntu is an established brand, with many supporters and a good reputation most likely some sponsor will buy them out and continue. But this is not going to happen some time soon. Also such a speculative question is usually <del>deleted</del> closed here.

Comment: i find this response from con-f-use as to censorship alarming and depressing

Comment: Sorry if I am being harsh but its responses like your that scare newbies away! Afterall, Ubuntu prides itself as 'Linux for human beings'

Comment: Say that again! All I wanted was an answer to a sensible question. Its because of people like him they say Ubuntu is not USER FRIENDLY! Lol

Comment: I did find my answer particularly harsh. It's just that this site is meant to provide definite answers to specific problems. Not to play clairvoyant. From the flag-options on this site: " We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; [...] Highly speculative questions are not the purpose of this site."

Comment: From the FAQ: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page." You'll not find questions about next week's weather either.

Comment: How am i being clairvoyant here? I did not state that i forsaw such a happening. If anything it was just a theory or an hypothesis READ THE POST AGAIN!

Comment: I read it. You are asking "what will happen if he (Mark Shuttlesworth [sic]) [...] suddenly withdraws his funds from the Ubuntu project". Future tense. You're asking for speculations about a future event.

Comment: @bernard let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/887/discussion-between-con-f-use-and-bernard)

Comment: This sort of thing is best discussed on a site best suited for discussions, like ubuntu forums or a mailing list.